# Java Regex for changing every ith index in every word of a string

Tags: java, regex

I've written a regex `\b\S\w(\S(?=.))` to find every third symbol in a word and replace it with '1'. Now I'm trying to use this expression but really don't know how to do it right.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\S\\w(\\S(?=.))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("lemon apple strawberry pumpkin");

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print(matcher.group(1) + " ");
}
```

So result is:

```
m p r m
```

And how can I use this to make a string like this

```
le1on ap1le st1awberry pu1pkin
```

Comment: do you really need to use regex here?

Comment: Yes. This is my task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
"lemon apple strawberry pumpkin".replaceAll("(?<=\\b\\S{2})\\S", "1")
```

Would produce your example output. The regex would replace any non space character preceded by two non space characters and then a word boundary.

This means that "words" like `12345` would be changed into `12145` since `3` is matched by `\\S` (not space).

**Edit:** 
Updated the regex to better cater to the revised question title, change `2` to `i-1` to replace the ith letter of the word.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to access the index of the **matcher**

Like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\S\\w(\\S(?=.))");
String string = "lemon apple strawberry pumpkin";
char[] c = string.toCharArray();
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
   while (matcher.find()) {
         c[matcher.end() - 1] = '1';////// may be it's not perfect , but this way in case of you want to access the index in which the **sring** is matches with the pattern
   }
System.out.println(c);
```